# Java: Using Iterator in Switch Statement

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, iterator, switch-statement

I want to cycle through an `ArrayList<String>` named `fileContent`, using the `Iterator interface`, and I want it to be analyzed one string at a time which should result in a specific state by the `switch statement`, depending on what string it is. 
Object token is supposed to be read as 'Table'.

```
        void process() {

        Iterator fileIterator = fileContent.iterator();

        int state = 0;
        Object token = null;
        switch (state) {

        case 0:
            token = fileIterator.next();
            if (token.equals("Table")) {
                System.out.println(token);
                state = 1;
            } else {
                System.err.println("Corrupt file format at state 0: "+ token);
                System.exit(0);
            }
            break;
        }

    }
```

This doesn't switch state to 1, instead it prints out:

```
'Corrupt file format at state 0: Table'
```

So it seems as it reads the Object token correctly as 'Table' but not for the statement `'if (token.equals("Table"))'`. 
I have also tried `'if (token == ("Table"))'`

Can somebody help me?

Comment: What if you do `"Table".equals(token.toString())`?

Comment: I would go into debug and see what token really is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to equate Strings, try this

```
    void process() {

    Iterator fileIterator = fileContent.iterator();

    int state = 0;
    String token = "";  // notice this
    switch (state) {

    case 0:
        token = ((String)fileIterator.next()).trim();  // notice this
        if (token.equals("Table")) {
            System.out.println(token);
            state = 1;
        } else {
            System.err.println("Corrupt file format at state 0: "+ token);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: There's pretty much zero reason to think that `token` is definitely a String, though.

Comment: OP was trying to equate token to "Table", isnt that reason enough ?

Comment: You've been here long enough to know it isn't

Comment: No, you'd still be making an assumption. What if `token` is an instance of some custom class, and calling `equals(String)` simply compares the value of one of its fields to the argument passed? Or `equals(String)` compares the result of calling `toString()` to the argument passed? Or the OP is just doing something they think should work but doesn't actually make any sense given the objects they're working with?

Comment: token is supposed to be read as a String because   ArrayList<String> fileContent

Comment: @FelixFortoul I totally missed that, have a tendency to skim the text and focus on the code. Good spot.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist no worries

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If fileContent is a String list, then it doesn't matter if you define `token` as `String` or `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think "it reads the Object token correctly as 'Table'"? When the `if()` fails, then `token` must be something unlike `Table`. My guess is that the output is misleading. Try this instead:

```
System.err.println("Corrupt file format at state 0: ["+ token + "]");
```

The square brackets around the token will help you see unexpected whitespace characters.

Also note that `token` might not be a string but return `Table` when `toString()` is called on it (which will happen if you append it to a string).

Comment: Because I tried printing it out before inserting the if -else statement.